# fs.stats does not provide the required states of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to get the file states of a specific .js file. so i used the below posted code

**code**:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var path = require
('../../var/opt/personal/guest/op/op_12201/data/persGuesOapDataFolder00/test0');

var mode = fs.stats(path);
var writePermissions = mode & 0x92; // 010010010
console.log(mode);
```

**error**:

```
var mode = fs.stats(path);
TypeError: fs.stats is not a function
```

Comment: it should be `fs.stat`

Comment: your `var path = require(...)` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I felt the same, but it does if the file is exports like `module.exports = "/Users/kiddo/file.js"` (although very ambigous)

Answer (score 1):

It should be [`fs.stat`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback)

> Asynchronous stat(2). The callback gets two arguments (err, stats) where stats is an fs.Stats object.

I hope that `path` is the file path.
Async version:

```
fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {console.log(stats)})
```

looking at your code, you may be wishing for [sync version](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path)

```
var mode = fs.statSync(path)
```

Comment: Also the `path` should be the string itself, not whatever the result of invoking the file as a module with `require()` ends up doing (most likely throwing an error)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I completely agree with you :). I indicated that in answer that I hope it's the file path, whichever way the user is intending to get it.